# Rails class method is thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I have this method in a class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def answers
    @answers ||= HTTParty.get("http://www.example.com/api/users/#{self.id}/answers.json")
  end

  ...
end
```

Since I'm using Puma as a web server I'm wondering if this code is thread safe? can someone confirm it and if possible explain why this is thread safe?

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge on `puma`, separate puma threads do not share the same `user` instance. Hence will make separate GET request in each puma thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This in an instance method, not to be confused with a class method. The `answers` method is on an *instance* of `User`, as opposed to being on the `User` class itself. This method is caching the answers on the instance of a `User`, but as long as this `User` instance is being instantiated with each web request (such as a `User.find()`or `User.find_by()`), you’re fine because the instance is not living between threads. It’s common practice to look records up every web request in the controller, so you’re likely doing that.

If this method was on the `User` class directly (such as `User.answers`), then you’d need to evaluate whether it’s safe for that cached value to be maintained across threads and web requests.

To recap, the your only concern for thread safety is class methods, class variables (instance variables that use two at signs such as `@@answers`), and instance methods where the instance lives on past a single web request.

If you ever find yourself needing to use a class-level variable safely, you can use `Thread.current`, which is essentially a per-thread Hash (like {}) that you can store values in. For example `Thread.current[:foo] = 1` would be an example. ActiveSupport uses this when setting `Time.zone`.

Alternatively you may find times where you need a single array that you need to safely share across threads, in which case you’d need to look into `Mutex`, which basically lets you have an array that you lock and unlock to give threads safe access to reading and writing in it. The Sidekiq gem uses a Mutex to manage workers, for example. You lock the Mutex, so that no one else can change it, then you write to it, and then unlock it. It’s important to note that if any other thread wants to write to the Mutex while it’s locked, it’ll have to wait for it to become unlocked (like, the thread just pauses while the other thread writes), so it’s important to lock as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you verify if the instance method does or does not live past a single web request?

Comment: @Crashalot For an object instance to be used in multiple web requests (potentially unsafe), you’d need to be using a class variable, class level instance variable, constant, or thread local variable. It’d probably be easier if you just posted a question with relevant code.